# Napster API Auth - BAD Request / Unauthorized

Tags: reactjs, api

I am coding in `Reactjs` and trying to **Auth/Outh** into the **Napster Web API**, followed the information on this page: https://developer.napster.com/api/v2.2#authentication

**A sample of my current code:**

```
const API_KEY = 'OWIxMjhlY2MtOTA3Yi00NWJiLThiYTktODc3OTNiYTQ4MGU4';
const API_KEY_SECRET = 'OWIxMjhlY2MtOTA3Yi00NWJiLThiYTktODc3OTNiYTQ4MGU4';
url: 'https://api.napster.com/oauth/access_token',
method: 'post',
params: {
    client_id: API_KEY,
    client_secret: API_KEY_SECRET
},
headers: {
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + (new Buffer(API_KEY + ':' + API_KEY_SECRET).toString('base64'))
},
data: querystring.stringify({ grant_type: 'authorization_code' })
```

**Response Payload:**

```
{"code":"UnauthorizedError","message":"Authentication code not valid"}
{"code":"BadRequestError","message":"Invalid grant_type parameter"}
```

Comment: Hi, @JohnSmith. I see your question and have a task related with napster integration. If you are interested in this, please contact me via skype(live:.cid.4aef4dc70c497975) or gmail(oldcrocodile128@gmail.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation and sample below....

```
curl -v -X POST -d "client_id={api_key}&client_secret={api_secret}&response_type=code&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&code={temporary_code}" "https://api.napster.com/oauth/access_token"
```

...You don't need to send Authorization headers. It's a normal form post with all the parameters. So If you include the rest of the parameters along with client_id : API_KEY... it should do the trick.

Comment: Interested. I will check this. What about authentication_code?